# Legacy ArcGIS system on Windows 2012 with ArcSDE 10.2.2 won't connect

Tags: arcgis, geotools

I'm currently working on a legacy system that's being rewritten by another contractor.  Our mandate is to just keep the lights on until the rewrite is complete.  So I understand all of what I'm listing is very old and out of date.

We have a java process that makes a direct connection to a 10.1 SDE.  On windows 2008 server it works fine and everything is great.  With windows 2008 coming to end of life we have to move to Windows 2012 or 2016.  We have a sandbox setup for both environments.  But using the same exact setup as on the Windows 2008 server, we get a very generic error

We believe the problem is in the connection binaries of the ArcSDE 10.2.2 library we are using.

The technologies we are using that seem to encapsulate the process that's failing:
Oracle 12c,
IBM Java 7,
Geotools 10.6, and 
ArcSDE 10.2.2 (With a few ArcSDE 9.3 dll's thrown in, this may be key but we aren't sure.  Specifically sdejavautil.dll)

The error we are getting is:

```
2019-12-11 22:56:31,454 ERROR [Thread-19] wfdss.framework.gis.geotools.ArcSDEFacade (ArcSDEFacade.java:165)   - org.geotools.arcsde.ArcSdeException: Can't create connection to 10.1.10.92 for Session #1[SDE error -51 Unknown error][Error desc=DATABASE LEVEL ERROR OCCURRED.][Extended desc=Unknown error
]
    at org.geotools.arcsde.session.Session$CreateSeConnectionCommand.execute(Session.java:621)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.session.Session$CreateSeConnectionCommand.execute(Session.java:575)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.session.Session.issue(Session.java:180)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.session.Session.<init>(Session.java:166)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.session.SessionPool$SeConnectionFactory.makeObject(SessionPool.java:384)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.session.SessionPool.<init>(SessionPool.java:155)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.session.SessionPoolFactory.createPool(SessionPoolFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.ArcSDEDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(ArcSDEDataStoreFactory.java:268)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.ArcSDEDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(ArcSDEDataStoreFactory.java:259)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.geotools.ArcSDEFacade.getDataStore(ArcSDEFacade.java:176)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.geotools.ArcSDEFacade.getFeatureSource(ArcSDEFacade.java:154)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.geotools.ArcSDEFacade.getTransform(ArcSDEFacade.java:738)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.geotools.ReferenceShape.getProjectedGeometryBasedOnReferencePoint(ReferenceShape.java:593)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.geotools.CommonGeoOps.getDistanceInMilesBetweenPointAndPoly(CommonGeoOps.java:2819)
    at wfdss.framework.database.assessment.IncidentShapeBizFacade.checkIfFirePerimeterExceedsMaxDistToPtOfOrigin(IncidentShapeBizFacade.java:96)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.ShapeFileHandler.uploadShape(ShapeFileHandler.java:556)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.ShapeFileHandler.processShapes(ShapeFileHandler.java:255)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.ShapeFileHandler.processUpload(ShapeFileHandler.java:199)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.service.ShapeService$ShapeThread.shapeUpload(ShapeService.java:824)
    at wfdss.framework.gis.service.ShapeService$ShapeThread.run(ShapeService.java:462)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
Caused by: com.esri.sde.sdk.client.SeException: Unknown error
    at com.esri.sde.sdk.client.SeConnection.x(Unknown Source)
    at com.esri.sde.sdk.client.SeConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.arcsde.session.Session$CreateSeConnectionCommand.execute(Session.java:610)
    ... 21 more
```

The line of code that's failing is below.  Again, all of the passed in params are the same as what's working on 2008.  Something inside the createDataStore method is failing.  Just looking for ideas if anyone has anything to share if they had a similar experience.

```
ArcSDEDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(dataStoreParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being that we needed to install the SDE and JDK binaries using the "compatibility" setting for the install exe.

To do that you just right click on any exe, go to properties, there's a "compatibility" tab.  Then just choose the version of windows you want to make ti compatible with.

Answer (score 0):

don't see too many GIS questions on here so thats why I clicked.  Past Gis and geologist guy here.

I did some research and found this article.  Hopefully its an easy fix as it was for this person.
http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=1003011

If not I think maybe updating certain drivers that are being utilized by the methods may help.  I remember having an issue with some sort of connection and I had to make sure all the drivers matched with what I was using.  Also checking to make sure if the drivers I was using were the correct bit.

Sorry I don't have an exact solution, but just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I greatly appreciate it.  I tried updating the password to a simple text password, but still getting the same error.